# Animation with ng-if

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

Am a bit stuck with getting my head around a basic fade-in and fade-out using Angularjs.

I am displaying the results of values I am returning from a database using the ng-if and want to fade in the results and fade it out upon clicking it again, based on whether this condition is met (`ng-if="detail.categoryId === expense.categoryId"`) As I have it now it fades in and then immediately fades out again when clicking on it once.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row expenseBreakdown fade" ng-if="detail.categoryId === expense.categoryId" ng-repeat="detail in expensesDetail">
     <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseDetail}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.dateExpense|date}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseAmount|currency:"R"}</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fade.ng-enter {
     transition:0.5s linear all;
     opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
     opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-if` inside `ng-repeat` like

```
<div class="row expenseBreakdown fade" ng-repeat="detail in expensesDetail">
<div class="fade ng-enter ng-enter-active" ng-if="detail.categoryId == expense.categoryId">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseDetail}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.dateExpense|date}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseAmount|currency:"R"}}</div>
</div>
<div class="fade ng-enter" ng-if="detail.categoryId != expense.categoryId">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseDetail}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.dateExpense|date}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{detail.expenseAmount|currency:"R"}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```